# When should I use className={`styles["my-class"]`} on my react project?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I'am working with React in a project and we need to use a className={`styles["my-class"]`} in  SCSS, I looked on google to know more about `styles`, but I didn't found anything.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the css modules method

You can read about it here
https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).